# How do I view an image in a new buffer in emacs?

Tags: images, pdf

I have the path to a pdf file or a png file (whichever is easiest to show, but bonus points for showing both).

How do I show the image in a new buffer? (It makes no sense to show it inline since it is a graph representation of the makefile I am writing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to open the file directly - `C-x C-f`, and Emacs will display it as you expect.

If you're running GNU/Linux, the [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) package provides a much-improved experience for viewing pdfs than the built-in Emacs viewer. pdf-tools isn't available for Windows, and I think may require some extra work on to get it running on Macs (?).

To do this in an elisp program, use the function `(find-file <path>)`, where  is the path to your file, as a string. e.g., `(find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el")` will open your init file.

Comment: Is there a way to open the file like that, but in a function? Thanks, btw.

Comment: Yes, see the revised answer.

Comment: And I was messing around with image-mode and similar. Much too easy.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `find-file`, if the image is referenced by URL, then `browse-url-emacs` is also an option.

```
(browse-url-emacs url)
```

Will download the image and generate a temporary buffer displaying it inline.